# Can't install packages React application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

When I type npm install I get this  [up to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6JAd.png)

I tried changing my npm versions and also npm update. Removed the resolutions and preinstall from the package.json. Also tried to removed the package-lock.json file and then installed it, still the same.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't debug images here. You need to tell us what you _expect_ to happen. Are the packages not already installed? How do you know?

Answer (score 0):

1.Clear npm Cache:

Sometimes, issues in npm cache can cause unexpected behavior. Try clearing the npm cache by running:

**npm cache clean -f**

2.Check Global npm Version:

Ensure that your global npm version is also up to date. You can update it using:

**npm install -g npm@latest**

3.Use --force Flag:

You can try forcing npm to reinstall all packages by using the --force flag:

**npm install --force**

hope you will find peace!

Comment: nothing worked, I used yarn to install the packages then